# Trying to learn boost::Intrusive Q1

Tags: c++11, boost

I have this program that I downloaded from the internet. If I add the clear at the end, it crashes with this message:

```
idf@idf-Satellite-C55t-A ~/Documents/BOOST_INTRUSIVE/Intrusive1/bin/Debug $ ./Intrusive1 
Intrusive1: /usr/local/include/boost/intrusive/detail/utilities.hpp:366: void boost::intrusive::detail::destructor_impl(Hook&, boost::intrusive::detail::link_dispatch<(boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)1u>) [with Hook = boost::intrusive::generic_hook<boost::intrusive::get_list_node_algo<void*>, boost::intrusive::member_tag, (boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)1u, (boost::intrusive::base_hook_type)0u>]: Assertion `!hook.is_linked()' failed.
Aborted
idf@idf-Satellite-C55t-A ~/Documents/BOOST_INTRUSIVE/Intrusive1/bin/Debug $
```

Not sure what that all means. I am hoping to clear all the items, and that the contents get deleted.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/intrusive/list.hpp>

using namespace boost::intrusive;

class MyClass : public list_base_hook<>   //This is a derivation hook
{
    int anInt;

public:
    //This is a member hook
    list_member_hook<> member_hook_;

    MyClass(int i)
        :  anInt(i)
    {}
};

//Define a list that will store MyClass using the public base hook
typedef list<MyClass>   BaseList;

//Define a list that will store MyClass using the public member hook
typedef list< MyClass
            , member_hook< MyClass, list_member_hook<>, &MyClass::member_hook_>
            > MemberList;

int main()
{
    typedef std::vector<MyClass>::iterator VectIt;

    //Create several MyClass objects, each one with a different value
    std::vector<MyClass> values;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        values.push_back(MyClass(i));

    BaseList baselist;
    MemberList memberlist;

    //Now insert them in the reverse order in the base hook list
    for(VectIt it(values.begin()), itend(values.end()); it != itend; ++it)
        baselist.push_front(*it);

    //Now insert them in the same order as in vector in the member hook list
    for(VectIt it(values.begin()), itend(values.end()); it != itend; ++it)
        memberlist.push_back(*it);

    //Now test lists
    {
        BaseList::reverse_iterator rbit(baselist.rbegin());
        MemberList::iterator mit(memberlist.begin());
        VectIt  it(values.begin()), itend(values.end());

        //Test the objects inserted in the base hook list
        for(; it != itend; ++it, ++rbit)
            if(&*rbit != &*it)   return 1;

        //Test the objects inserted in the member hook list
        for(it = values.begin(); it != itend; ++it, ++mit)
            if(&*mit != &*it)    return 1;

        values.clear();
        //Now delete all the values. Do they dissapear from all containers?
           //Now insert them in the reverse order in the base hook list
        //for(VectIt it(values.begin()), itend(values.end()); it != itend; ++it)
        //    ;

        //std::cout << values.size();
        //std::cout << baselist.size();
        //std::cout << memberlist.size();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intrusive containers don't *own* their elements. The elements must be stored out-of-band.

What you're doing is delete the elements, while they're still logically inserted into (several) intrusive collections (i.e. they are *linked* through their intrusive *hooks*).

In [safe mode](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/intrusive/safe_hook.html#intrusive.safe_hook.features), Boost Intrusive will actually diagnose this in the destructor of the hook structs, which is why you get the error message.

See also: [auto-unlink hooks](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/intrusive/auto_unlink_hooks.html#intrusive.auto_unlink_hooks.auto_unlink_hooks_what)

Comment: I see. One question, say I want the element removed from ALL intrusive containers that contain it. Will just calling delete on the element do the trick?

Comment: @Ivan I thought this was the object of your experiments? ([here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c82295df07315cae)). As long as you clear the lists before the storage you're ok.

Comment: And here's **[the auto-unlink version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62c48efddbe22985)**. Note how clearing `values` also cleared the lists. Also, be sure to read the caveats (e.g. threading) with auto-unlink containers.

Comment: sehe, thank you once again. I am getting there be patient. I have more questions, but I want to struggle and suffer first while I try to make all the connections in my mind. Already making use of BOOST::Variant, BOOST::Intrusive, and boost::lexical_cast.

Comment: @Ivan I love that. I don't _like_ to struggle, but I do realize it's required for me to learn